# Barplot with multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, multi-index

Is there a way to plot 'client_nr' versus 'Credit Total':

Example:

[image]

Current code:

```
credit_clients.iloc[-1].plot.bar()
```

Which produces:

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFIPp.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `df.iloc[-1].T.plot()` ??

Comment: This is coming really close @Nk03! Could you elaborate on .T?

Comment: .T is used to transpose the dataframe 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have synthesized data that is similar to your dataframe
- plotting is simple, just need to select **Client Total** from index using `.loc[]`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# synthesize data
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range("1-jan-2018", freq="M", periods=6), range(10)], names=["yearmonth","client_nr"])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=i, data=np.random.uniform(1,10, len(i))).unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df.loc["Client Total"] = df.sum(axis=0)

# plot it...
df.loc["Client Total"].plot(kind="bar")
```

#### data

| yearmonth | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-31 00:00:00 | 8.48257 | 9.38166 | 9.14367 | 7.52485 | 8.25407 | 4.9672 | 8.28687 | 2.96698 | 9.37681 | 2.36876 |
| 2018-02-28 00:00:00 | 5.99324 | 8.72813 | 6.06575 | 4.19694 | 8.03992 | 2.22363 | 9.56064 | 8.23965 | 6.97355 | 5.8883 |
| 2018-03-31 00:00:00 | 8.85086 | 8.48972 | 9.11997 | 7.91605 | 6.38338 | 9.33158 | 7.26467 | 8.00862 | 8.38145 | 6.81128 |
| 2018-04-30 00:00:00 | 7.69246 | 5.17472 | 7.73813 | 2.75313 | 7.12725 | 9.86623 | 2.16481 | 8.15056 | 6.81378 | 9.01334 |
| 2018-05-31 00:00:00 | 6.05941 | 3.29547 | 7.05862 | 9.83301 | 4.51411 | 4.11672 | 7.53534 | 5.52747 | 8.34065 | 3.13277 |
| 2018-06-30 00:00:00 | 9.7033 | 9.36859 | 4.35592 | 4.4328 | 5.61218 | 1.13454 | 9.63189 | 3.44345 | 6.60661 | 4.43206 |
| Client Total | 46.7818 | 44.4383 | 43.4821 | 36.6568 | 39.9309 | 31.6399 | 44.4442 | 36.3367 | 46.4928 | 31.6465 |

#### plot

[image]

#### bars coloured by client_nr - use plotly

```
import plotly.express as px
px.bar(df.loc["Client Total"].reset_index(), x="client_nr", y="Client Total", color="client_nr")
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful @Rob Raymond! Is there a way to make the bar plot visually more appealing when the client_nr is large?

Comment: have updated - if you want more appealing charts I recommend using plotly instead of matplotlib